# Hide status message in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, java-me, status

A status message can be displayed in Blackberry using method `show` of class `net.rim.device.api.ui.component.Status`. Using this method you specify a certain amount of time that the message should be displayed but, is there any way to hide this status message BEFORE this time?

I am using this code for displaying status messages in my application:

```
public static void status(final String message, final int time) {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { public void run() { Status.show(message, time); } });
}
```

EDIT: Solution that worked for me (thanks to Eugen Martynov solution)

```
public static void hideStatus() {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
        public void run() {
            Screen activeScreen = UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen();
            if (activeScreen instanceof Status) {
                activeScreen.close();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [javadoc](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/ui/component/Status.html) there no concrete method to close status.

However you could try to ask `UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen()` and try to call `close()` of it